# Unable to read "&" in DropDown html on IE11

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a dropdown in which I am binding a list which have following below values:

```
A
B
C&D
```

My dropdown is showing all these three values on FireFox but on IE it is showing A,B,C i.e. unable to read value "C&D". Please suggest

**UPDATE:**

```
 if (data.d != null) {
                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                    $("#dropdownId").append($("<option title='" + value.Description + "'></option>").val(value.ReferenceTypeValue).html(value.ReferenceTypeValue));
                });
            }
```

Comment: have you trid using &amp; instead of &?

Comment: ReferenceTypeValue="C&D"? What is the value of value.Description? If it includes an apostrophe it will break the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with your values.

You can use these function

http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/HTML-Encode-and-Decode-with-jQuery/39816

Comment: You are right, but I am binding my dropdown using jquery. Is there any way to encode the HTML using Jquery

Comment: @user3590502 Include your jQuery in the question, and most likely use Bushan Kawadkar's suggestion `&amp`.

Comment: Updated Jquery in my question